# How do I pass a hash to subroutine?

Tags: perl, hash, subroutine

Need help figuring out how to do this. My code:

```
my %hash;
$hash{'1'}= {'Make' => 'Toyota','Color' => 'Red',};
$hash{'2'}= {'Make' => 'Ford','Color' => 'Blue',};
$hash{'3'}= {'Make' => 'Honda','Color' => 'Yellow',};


&printInfo(%hash);

sub printInfo{
   my (%hash) = %_;
   foreach my $key (keys %_{       
    my $a = $_{$key}{'Make'};   
    my $b = $_{$key}{'Color'};   
    print "$a $b\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The easy way, which may lead to problems when the code evolves, is simply by assigning the default array @_ (which contains all key-value-pairs as an even list) to the %hash which then rebuilds accordingliy. So your code would look like this:

```
sub printInfo {
   my %hash = @_;
   ...
}
```

The better way would be to pass the hash as reference to the subroutine. This way you could still pass more parameters to your subroutine.

```
printInfo(\%hash);
sub PrintInfo {
   my %hash = %{$_[0]};
   ...
}
```

An introduction to using references in Perl can be found in the [perlreftut](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/pod/perlreftut.pod)

Comment: The second option is the best way to do this.

Comment: How can I use `shift` instead of `$_[0]`? When I tried `%{shift}`, the Perl interpreter resolved this as `%shift`, which is/was undefined. I would appreciate your input.

Comment: Just make clear, that you want to call the shift-function: `%{shift()}`.

Answer (score 9):

You're so very, very close.  There is no `%_` for passing hashes, it must be passed in `@_`.  Luckily, Hashes are assigned using a list context, so

```
sub printInfo {
   my %hash = @_;
   ...
}
```

will make it work!

Also note, using the `&` in front of the subroutine call has been, in most cases, unnecessary since at least Perl 5.000.  You can call Perl subroutines just like in other languages these days, with just the name and arguments.  (As @mob points out in the comments, there are some instances where this is still necessary; see [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) to understand this more, if interested.)

Comment: `&` is usually optional, and it is (often) not a best practice to use it because of the way Perl generates default arguments, but it's not deprecated. Sometimes it is required and sometimes it is not required but it can still make the code more readable.

Comment: You, sir, are technically correct: the best kind of correct.  I've clarified my comment on that.

Comment: Not *“and maybe older”*. The `&` was still **usually** needed on function calls in the last perl4 version 4.036 of 1993-Feb-05.  Trust me, I was there. ☺ The only way to avoid it was to use the `do mysubname()` syntax — which still works fine, by the way, much the surprise of those few who stumble upon it.  Or over it.

Comment: @mob `&subname` is still used for `defined` and `undef` arguments, or the operand of the ` \\ ` or `goto` operators. For invocation, it is used to circumvent prototype checking. `&foo()` is kind to your `@_`, while `&foo` without parens is stealthy. `goto &foo` might be clearer for tail-recursion, save that you can’t here from there.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to pass hashes and arrays is by [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). A reference is simply a way to talk about a complex data structure as a single data point -- something that can be stored in a *scalar variable* (like `$foo`).

Read up on [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), so you understand how to create a reference and *dereference* a reference in order to get your original data back.

The very basics: You precede your data structure with a backslash to get the *reference* to that structure.

```
my $hash_ref   = \%hash;
my $array_ref  = \@array;
my $scalar_ref = \$scalar;   #Legal, but doesn't do much for you...
```

A reference is a memory location of the original structure (plus a clue about the structure):

```
print "$hash_ref\n";
```

Will print something like:

```
HASH(0x7f9b0a843708)
```

To get the reference back into a useable format, you simply put the reference into the correct  [sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29) in front:

```
my %new_hash = %{ $hash_ref };
```

You should learn about using references since this is the way you can create extremely complex data structures in Perl, and how Object Oriented Perl works.

---

Let's say you want to pass three hashes to your subroutine. Here are the three hashes:

```
my %hash1 = ( this => 1, that => 2, the => 3, other => 4 );
my %hash2 = ( tom => 10, dick => 20, harry => 30 );
my %hash3 = ( no => 100, man => 200, is => 300, an => 400, island => 500 );
```

I'll create the references for them

```
my $hash_ref1 = \%hash1;
my $hash_ref2 = \%hash2;
my $hash_ref3 = \%hash3;
```

And now just pass the references:

```
mysub ( $hash_ref1, $hash_ref2, $hash_ref3 );
```

The references are *scalar* data, so there's no problem passing them to my subroutine:

```
sub mysub {
    my $sub_hash_ref1  = shift;
    my $sub_hash_ref2  = shift;
    my $sub_hash_ref3  = shift;
```

Now, I just dereference them, and my subroutine can use them.

```
    my %sub_hash1 = %{ $sub_hash_ref1 };
    my %sub_hash2 = %{ $sub_hash_ref2 };
    my %sub_hash3 = %{ $sub_hash_ref3 };
```

You can see what a reference is a reference to by using the [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) command:

```
my $ref_type = ref $sub_hash_ref;    # $ref_type is now equal to "HASH"
```

This is useful if you want to make sure you're being passed the correct type of data structure.

```
sub mysub {
    my $hash_ref = shift;

    if ( ref $hash_ref ne "HASH" ) {
        croak qq(You need to pass in a hash reference);
    }
```

Also note that these are memory references, so modifying the reference will modify the original hash:

```
my %hash = (this => 1, is => 2, a => 3 test => 4);
print "$hash{test}\n";   # Printing "4" as expected
sub mysub ( \%hash );    # Passing the reference
print "$hash{test}\n";   # This is printing "foo". See subroutine:


sub mysub { 
    my $hash_ref = shift;

    $hash_ref->{test} = "foo";    This is modifying the original hash!
}
```

This can be good -- it allows you to modify data passed to the subroutine, or bad -- it allows you to *unintentionally* modify data passed to the original subroutine.

Comment: what if the subroutines are nested. I have `sub1(\%hash)` then it calls another subroutine, by doing `sub2($hash->{$i})` and then this one calls yet another nested  `sub3($local)`. Where local is defined by `my ($local)=@_;`. Actually, all subs use this method to get the variables. If I wanted to call `sub3` as standalone. What argument does it need? `$hash->{$i}` is an array. i.e. each hash element is an array?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you want

```
my %hash;
$hash{'1'}= {'Make' => 'Toyota','Color' => 'Red',};
$hash{'2'}= {'Make' => 'Ford','Color' => 'Blue',};
$hash{'3'}= {'Make' => 'Honda','Color' => 'Yellow',};

printInfo(%hash);

sub printInfo{
   my %hash = @_;
   foreach my $key (keys %hash){       
    my $a = $hash{$key}{'Make'};   
    my $b = $hash{$key}{'Color'};   
    print "$a $b\n";
   }
}
```

In the line `printInfo(%hash)` the `%hash` is expanded to a list with the alternating key-value pairs.

In `printInfo`, the `@_` is this list that, and assigned to `%hash` it creates again the keys with their corresponding value from the alternating elements in the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass them as

1. The argument list `do_hash_thing( %hash )`
2. A reference to the hash in the argument list 
   `do_hash_thing( @args_before, \%hash, @args_after )
3. As a reference by *prototype*, working like `keys` and other hash operators.

The list works like so:

```
sub do_hash_thing {
    my %hash = @_;
    ...
}

do_hash_thing( %hash );
```

This also allows you to "stream" hash arguments as well:

```
do_hash_thing( %hash_1, %hash_2, parameter => 'green', other => 'pair' );
```

By reference works like this:

```
sub do_hash_thing { 
    my $hash_ref = shift;
    ...
}

do_hash_thing( \%hash, @other_args );
```

Here by prototype `(\%@)`. The prototype makes perl look for a hash in the first argument and pass it by reference.

```
sub do_hash_thing (\%@) { 
    my $hash_ref = shift;
    ...
}

do_hash_thing( %hash => qw(other args) );
# OR
do_hash_thing %hash => qw(other args);
```

Caveat: prototypes don't work on methods.